# MIPS returned value not correct

Tags: assembly, mips

I have this C function:

```
int bin_img(unsigned char *ptr, int w, int h, unsigned char limiar);
```

On my code I use my function like this:

```
printf("The value is %d\n",bin_img(dp, width, height, LIMIAR));
```

Imagine the variables are defined like this:

```
#define LIMIAR 128
unsigned char *dp;
int w = 5;
int h = 0;

dp[] = {74,250,153,28,26}
```

I have to program my bin_img function in MIPS.

Imagine I have this code:

```
bin_img:

    lb  $15,0($4)   
    move    $2,$15
    jr  $31
```

It will print 74 witch is the firs element of my array.
If I do

```
bin_img:

    lb  $15,1($4)   
    move    $2,$15
    jr  $31
```

or this:

```
bin_img:

    lb  $15,2($4)   
    move    $2,$15
    jr  $31
```

It will print some negative numbers and if I do this:

```
bin_img:

    lb  $15,3($4)   
    move    $2,$15
    jr  $31
```

or this

```
bin_img:

    lb  $15,4($4)   
    move    $2,$15
    jr  $31
```

It will print 28 and 26 respectively. Why is it printing negative numbers?

Should'n it print 250 and 153?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is printing negative numbers because you are using the signed version of LoadByte `lb` instead of the unsigned version `lbu`.

The `lb` instruction reads a byte from memory and stores it in the 8 least significant bits of the destination register and sets the 24 remaining bits with the value of the most significant bit of the byte read. The `lbu` instruction sets those 24 bits with zero.

Therefore, the syscall you are issuing to print the number treats the register contents as A2 compliment thus printing negative numbers when your input byte is >= 128. To fix your program, you should use the `lbu` instruction.

Comment: Thanks. Solved verifying if the read number was greater than 0. If not, added 255. Your solution is the correct one and soooooo much easier. Many thanks